# How can I get all the children from within an array stored on firebase (using Android)?

Tags: android, json, loops, firebase

I have a list of "messages" stored on firebase. I would like to get the entire list and be able to iterate through them. How can I do this in android?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase contains own documentation for retrieving data you can visit this link

> https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Data is retrieved by using this method

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("height");

    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
            Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>)snapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(snapshot.getKey() + " was " + value.get("height") + " meters tall");
        }
        // ....
    });
```

here all data come in DataSnapshot and you perform all operations.